# find the max for each value in SQL

Tags: sql

i have tables like this

### table 1

```
|cl.1| 
| -- | 
| a  | 
| b  |
| c  |
```

table 2

```
|cl.1|cl.2|para|
|----|---| --- |
| a  | 3 |  t  |
| a  | 3 |  f  |
| b  | 2 |  t  |
| a  | 1 |  b  |
| c  | 4 |  t  |
| b  | 7 |  d  |
```

i want to get the max value for each element in table1 from table2
and the different `parameter`
so the expecited tabel should be like this

```
|cl.1|max|para|
|----|---| --- |
| a  | 3 |  t  |
| a  | 3 |  f  |
| c  | 4 |  t  |
| b  | 7 |  d  |
```

Comment: Why do you want both t and f for a, but only d for b?

Comment: in case that the max has more than one max values , then i have to print it  if it have different parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to compute all the maximums:

```
with Maxes as (
    select cl1,
           max(cl2) as cl2
      from Table2
  group by cl1)
```

and then `join` them with the original `Table2`, e.g.

```
with Maxes as (
    select cl1,
           max(cl2) as cl2
      from Table2
  group by cl1)

select t.*
  from Table2 t join
       Maxes m on (t.cl1 = m.cl1 and t.cl2 = m.cl2)
```

Comment: in case that table number 2 is query select with count function  from another table  
{{{{ select cl.1  , count(cl.1) as cl.2  ,  para  from tabel group by  para  ,  cl.1 }}} 
wil it also working ?

Comment: @DOS HASAN: If I understand you right, you can well add `count(cl1)` or any other aggregate function: as far as `join` is kept intact we can add extra fields to query

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what features your RDBMS supports.

With Oracle you could do a CROSS APPLY to order table2 by descending cl2 and keep the top values (with ties):

```sql
select T1.c1, TM.maximum, TM.para
from Table1 T1
cross apply (
  select *
  from Table2 T2
  where T2.c1 = T1.c1
  order by T2.maximum descending
  fetch first 1 row with ties
) TM
```

You can do the same in SQL Server with syntax `select top 1 with ties` instead of `fetch first 1 row with ties`.

Another option could be to use *Analytical Functions* to rank the results per `col1` and then keep only the first ones.

```sql
select T.c1, T.maximum, T.para
from (
  select 
    T1.c1, T2.maximum, T2.para, 
    rank() over (partition by T1.c1 order by T2.maximum desc) r
  from T1
  join T2 on T1.c1 = T2.c2
) T
where T.r = 1
```

Less stylish and probably(?) less performant would be computing the maximum for each `c1` and then doing an equality:

```sql
select T1.c1, T2.maximum, T2.para
from T1
join T2 on T1.c1 = T2.c1
where T2.maximum = (select max(maximum) from T2 where c1 = T1.c1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get the max `tl.1` and if for the same values it is equal, you could try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table2
WHERE cl_2 in  ( SELECT MAX(cl_2) 
                 FROM table2 
                 group by cl_1 
);
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> cl_1  cl_2    para
> a       3      t
> a       3      f
> c       4      t
> b       7      d
> ```

Tested on `MySQL` : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=42a6bc20622a210b18101588540995ec

You could use a join , but it makes no difference:

```
SELECT t1.cl_1,t2.cl_2,t2.para 
FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN table1 t1 on t2.cl_1=t1.cl_1
WHERE t2.cl_2 in  (SELECT MAX(cl_2) FROM table2 group by cl_1 );
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4b2eed9bcee3532cc7c4e7b3862bc3ef

Answer (score 1):

DENSE_RANK can be used to get whole rows that have a maximum of something within a partition.

Because when sorted descending, the top 1 will have rank 1.

```
select cl_1, cl_2, para
from
(
    select cl_1, cl_2, para
    , dense_rank() over (partition by cl_1 order by cl_2 desc) as rnk
    from table1 t1
    join table2 t2 using (cl_1)
) q
where rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CTE` to get the max values, then select the rows with those values:

```
with maxes as 
(
    select t1.[cl.1]
        , max(t2.[cl.2]) max_val
    from table1 t1
    inner join table2 t2
        on t1.[cl.1] = t2.[cl.1]
    group by t1.[cl.1]
)
select t1.[cl.1]
    , t2.[cl.2]
    , t2.para
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
    on t1.[cl.1] = t2.[cl.1]
where t2.[cl.2] = (select m.max_val from maxes m where m.[cl.1] = t1.[cl.1])
```

This can also be achieved by joining the `CTE`:

```
with maxes as 
(
    select t1.[cl.1]
        , max(t2.[cl.2]) max_val
    from table1 t1
    inner join table2 t2
        on t1.[cl.1] = t2.[cl.1]
    group by t1.[cl.1]
)
select t1.[cl.1]
    , t2.[cl.2]
    , t2.para
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
    on t1.[cl.1] = t2.[cl.1]
inner join maxes m
    on t2.[cl.2] = m.max_val
```